# Flash Builder 4 Start Page?

Tags: flexbuilder, flash-builder

i have closed the Start Page in FB4 and now i can not find it.  ridiculous.  how can i open this panel again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's located here:

Help > Flash Builder Start Page

Answer (score 0):

window > welcome panel, something like this from the top menus in FB4.

Comment: it's not there.  was the first place i looked.  neither is it in Window > Other Views...  i have Flash Builder 4 Standard on Mac OS